# How to change width to fill the remaining space (CSS)

Tags: css, width

Take a look :

[image]

Result should be

[image]

Comment: +1 for lovely screenshot. But add the CSS code as well please

Comment: Were these screenshots made manually?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
#sidebar { float:left; width:280px; }
#content { margin: 0 0 0 280px; } /* dont float it */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/auTbG/1/

You will have problems if you have floats inside of #content and you try to clear them, though.

Comment: Very clever use of margins, even though doesn't feel entirely natural.

Answer (score 2):

Actually using css flex display can solve this easily.

Set the parent container to have

```
display: flex;
align-items: stretch;
align-content: stretch;
```

Then the children will have `flex-grow: 0;`

Make the last child have `flex-grow: 1;`

Put `#sidebar` and `#post_box` in `#content` and then

```
#content { display:flex; align-items: stretch; align-content: stretch; }
#sidebar { float:left; width:280px; flex-grow: 0; }
#post_box { float: left; flex-grow: 1; }
```